# Pandas write excel problem with boolean values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have dataframe in which one column has string values "True" or "False"
however using pd.to_excel an opening file with excel this column is different than regular exce "TRUE" (logical) co compring "True" from pandas with excel "True" return FALSE. Problem is solved when i export to CSV but then all other formatings are gone.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': ['True','False']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'H:\ExcelTest2.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Please execute my code. open xlsx file and in column 4 write regular "True" then compare Column3 (from pandas) with True you just wrote. it will be False

My question is: How i can export data from pandas to excel and keep "True" in same format as excel used to have.

Comment: Try to share an example with code.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your strings before writing to Excel like in following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['True', 'False', 'True']})
df['A'].dtype
#dtype('O')

df['A'] = df['A'] == 'True'
df['A'].dtype
#dtype('bool')
```

Comment: Please execute my code. open xlsx file and in column 4 write regular "True" then compare Column3 (from pandas) with True you just wrote. it will be False

Comment: Well, your answer gave me some idea what could go wrong in mode code. In some point my data was str so i had to use .astype(bool) before export to excel which makes "True" equal to excel "True"

Comment: @Drac0 I've miss-typed the `True` it should be `'True'`. Edited.